# Python range function

Tags: python, python-2.7, range

Say I want to loop from 0 to 100 but with a step of 1/2.  If you try

```py
for i in range(0, 100, 0.5):
    whatever
```

**Error:**

> the step must not be 0

**Question:**
Is there any built-in way in Python 2.x to do something like this?

Comment: Looking at some of the answers this would make an excellent reverse code golf question ...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Python2.x:**

```py
for idx in range(0, int(100 / 0.5)):

    print 0.5 * idx
```

**outputs:**

> 0.0
>
> 0.5
>
> 1.0
>
> 1.5
>
> ..
>
> 99.0
>
> 99.5

---

**Numpy:**

[`numpy.arange`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) would also do the trick.

```
numpy.arange(0, 100, 0.5)
```

Comment: Interesting approach, but I like it.  :)

Comment: @NPE Am I missing something here? Here is the result `TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got float.`

Comment: @gongzhitaao: You are quite right, this need an explicit conversion to `int` (see the edit). Since the answer was written over two years ago, I can't remember why I wrote it the way it is.

Answer (score 10):

If you have `numpy`, here are two ways to do it:

```
numpy.arange(0, 100, 0.5)

numpy.linspace(0, 100, 200, endpoint=False)
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to use integer steps for `range`() and `xrange()`. That's why your 0.5 step gets internally converted to 0 and you get that error. Try `for i in [j / 2.0 for j in xrange(100 * 2)]:`

Comment: Integer truncation occurs with this, so you just repeat each integer twice.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to either create the loop manually, or define your own custom range function.  The built-in requires an integer step value.

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in map(lambda i: i * 0.5, range(0,200)):
  #Do something with x
```

Comment: `map` and a lambda function for a simple iterable? Looks cool and functional programing-y but, in reality, it would just add unnecessary computational complexity.

Answer (score 0):

For large ranges it is better to use an generator expression than building a list explicitly:

```
 for k in ( i*0.5 for i in range(200) ):
     print k
```

This consumes not much extra memory, is fast und easy to read.
See http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions

Comment: In Python 2, you would be defeating the memory savings of a generator expression since range() produces a list; use xrange() instead.  In Python 3, xrange() replaces range().