# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable error in python3.9.1

Tags: python

I got this error in python3.9.1. I coded this in thonny.

```
numbers = [12, 23, 37, 42, 59, 67]
#print(numbers)
#index = 0
#for i in numbers:
    #print(numbers[index] + 19)
    #ndex = index + 1
#for x in numbers:
    #print(x)
    #print(x * x)

variable = 34
print("The number of the variable is: " + str(variable))
print("The list numbers are: " + str(numbers))
new_number = input("Input a new number, but smaller than the numbers listed above: ")

for var in variable:
    print(var * new_number)
```

Please help. :)

Comment: I think what you are looking for is `range(variable)` to run your `for` loop as: `for var in range(variable):`.

Comment: What is `for var in variable` supposed to do? `variable` is set to `34`, so that's equivalent to `for var in 34`. What is your intention with that statement? Are you trying to loop through all the digits in the decimal representation of that number? Or loop through a range of values from 0 to that number?

Comment: Random Davis, looks like a [Pascal's Triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle)

Answer (score 0):

Is normal that give an error, you can't have a for loop with a `int` data type so Use range function:

```
numbers = [12, 23, 37, 42, 59, 67]


variable = 34
print("The number of the variable is: " + str(variable))
print("The list numbers are: " + str(numbers))
new_number = input("Input a new number, but smaller than the numbers listed above:     ")

for var in range(variable):
    print(var * new_number)
```

**NOTE**

you can better understand how the range function works if you cast it as a list:

```
variable = 34
print(list(range(variable)))
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33]
```

### Documentation

- [func-range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range)
- [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp)

### Stack Overflow related

- [python-range-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531945/python-range-function)
- [range-function-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50575700/range-function-in-python/50775679)
- [range-function-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50575700/range-function-in-python/50575719#50575719)